# Python how to make a ping -t script looping indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, windows-10, subprocess

I want to run a python script file with this `ping -t www.google.com` command.

So far I did one with the `ping www.google.com` command which works, but I didn't suceed to do on with the `ping -t` looping indefinitely.

You can find below my `ping.py` script:

```
import subprocess

my_command="ping www.google.com"
my_process=subprocess.Popen(my_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

result, error = my_process.communicate()
result = result.strip()
error = error.strip()

print ("\nResult of ping command\n")
print("-" *22)
print(result.decode('utf-8'))
print(error.decode('utf-8'))
print("-" *22)
input("Press Enter to finish...")
```

I want the command box to stay open when finished. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: `while True` didn't work?

Comment: Don't ping from a subprocess, that's nonsense. There are native Python modules that implement the ICMP protocol, pick one of them.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm a beginner about Python sorry, which kind of module can I use instead? I'll be glad to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the process open and communicate with it all the time, you can use my_process.stdout as input and e.g. iterate over it's lines. With "communicate" you wait until the process completes, which would be bad for an indefinitely running process :)

```
import subprocess

my_command=["ping", "www.google.com"]
my_process=subprocess.Popen(my_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    print( my_process.stdout.readline() )
```

EDIT

In this version we use re to only get the "time=xxms" part from the output:

```
import subprocess
import re

my_command=["ping", "-t", "www.google.com"]
my_process=subprocess.Popen(my_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = my_process.stdout.readline() #read a line - one ping in this case
    line = line.decode("utf-8") #decode the byte literal to string
    line = re.sub("(?s).*?(time=.*ms).*", "\\1", line) #find time=xxms in the string and use only that

    print(line)
```

Comment: This seems to work by using  `ping` but crash if trying with `ping -t`

Comment: I currently can't test with windows, with linux it works fine. What did you try as "my_command"? It must look like this: my_command=["ping", "-t", "www.google.com"] (every part of the command as single entry in the list.

Comment: You are right, I was using it wrongly, thanks for your answer! by the way the output is currently`b'Reply from IP_ADDRESS: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=54\r\n'` Do you have an Idea how to hide both `b'` at beginning and `\r\n'` at the end ? I don't get why they are here. Or even better just display `time=15ms` *but that's another question.*

Comment: Yes, the "b" in front indicates a byte literal instead of a string. you can decode it to a string. The time=xxms can be extracted using re. I've updated my answer accordingly.